# How can detect that client change my js web code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, security

My question is,

If there is a way to detect (maybe an event) - if a user that browse to my web, has change my html/js code?

My goal is:
**for example:** 

To detect if someone has change my value that containd in `<input></input>` by the code. 

Or change an array that he found in my `js` that holds parameters

And if i will detect that he change something? he could not still using my web (in this session) until he refresh the page and get the authentic files again (without changes).

Comment: No. I just take a copy and use what I want to. You give away html and jquery

Comment: Well you could use JavaScript to scan the DOM and see if it differs, but then the user could just disable JavaScript entirely. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if it's because you don't want users editing the JavaScript and sending unexpected data -- you should just protect your back end by doing proper validation.

Comment: If you told [why you want to do this](http://xyproblem.info) then maybe someone could give an alternative way of achieving that goal.

Comment: That's better, but that's still not your actual goal. *Why* do you not want someone to change the value in input fields or JS arrays?

Comment: because he could send me back a value that i disallow it by js, but he can do it manually, and avoid from my check.
for example an input of phone he could change the name that i named it. or send something else in this `input` and In the server i will get null. of course i can check if there is a variable name like that.. but maybe a short way.

Comment: You can't prevent that by disallowing changes in HTML or JS. If someone wants to send bad data to your server they can do it even without a web browser. The only way to prevent that is to do server-side checks, just like Dave said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, *unless you are using javascript to send data to a server* you have than you could possibly include some sort of checking. **However that is not possible with client-side javascript.**

**If you use something like [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/) or similar** you could have the javascript on the server-side and you could insure that it does not get altered.

Sorry, I hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't have to be nodejs, any backend language will do :P

Comment: @kappaismyname True, I was just pulling the first server-side javascript backend I could think of. But that is true, you could pretty easily use any backend for this. :)

Answer (score -2):

The anwser is **YES**, you can, but only the HTML:

- To do this you have to set an interval to read all the DOM and then send it to back-end (where you have the initial state)
- You can't do this if there is a lot of DOM manipulation done by the JS (SPA apps). I mean, you can, but it's overkill
- This is overkill

There might be other methods to think about just for the love of a challenge but I don't see a practical reason to do this (There might be one but who cares about that).

All cross-browser issues are also addressed :P

Comment: Just replay the traffic

Comment: An actual reason why people downvote questions should be left in the comments. This answer it's pretty lame like the question is :)

Comment: thank you on your answare, i understand it but as you say, its seems to be overkill

Comment: Circumventing this would be trivial to anyone who knows how to manipulate the HTML/JS in the first place.

Comment: And once you know the page was changed, what you are going to do, if the code that manipulates what has to be done in this case was also changed/deleted. This becomes an infinite loop :)